# Object.getPrototypeOf not working?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm reading [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/magazine/ff852808%28en-us%29.aspx). It defines a simple array:

```
var myArray = [1, 2];
myArray.push(3);
myArray.reverse();
myArray.pop();
var length = myArray.length;
```

and then tries (and succeeds) in getting its prototype via Object.getPrototypeOf. However, when I tested this in Firebug and Chrome's console, I get an empty array. Why?.

However, when I do the same for an object (in this case, the point object defined in the same post), I actually get its prototype.

Comment: *"I get an empty array. Why?"* Because the `prototype` of the `Array` constructor is an `Array` object. See [ECMAScript 15.4.4 Properties of the Array Prototype Object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4) `The Array prototype object is itself an array; its [[Class]] is "Array"`

Comment: Yes, but it would make more sense to get the prototype when you ask for it by getPrototypeOf.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You are getting the prototype, and the prototype is an empty Array.

Comment: Uhm, not quite sure it's an empty array. Obviously, it has methods in it, even if they're are "hidden". I feel getPrototypeOf should show those methods since they are what you want when you call it.

Comment: Sure it has methods, but it doesn't change the fact that it's an empty Array. Array members are expected to be numeric indices. That doesn't preclude the ability to add non numeric properties. You're question suggests that you're not actually getting the prototype. I'm saying you are. If your actual point is that you want to know what methods are available on the prototype object, then do `console.dir(Array.prototype)` instead.

Comment: ...With respect to *"I feel getPrototypeOf should show those methods..."*, the `getPrototypeOf` method doesn't *show* anything. It simply retrieves the object. The developer tools decide what to show and not show, and there's no standard governing what should be displayed or how it should be displayed.

Comment: Oh, now I understand that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome's Developer Tools displays `Array.prototype` as an array, because it suffices the two requirements for this behaviour:

- having a `.length` property
- having a `.splice` function

Array instances have these properties, so you see arrays as actual arrays which is helpful. The problem is that `Array.prototype` also is an array according to Chrome's Developer Tools because of these rules ([which it also is](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4), but it's not a very helpful visualisation because it shouldn't have elements).

If you evaluate `Object.getPrototypeOf(myArray) === Array.prototype`, you'll get `true`. It's just Chrome's Developer Tools that doesn't display `Array.prototype` as you might expect.

Comment: Well, the same happens in Firebug, but I assume it applies the same rationale.

Comment: You seem to be implying that the prototype isn't actually an Array, and that Chrome is just interpreting it that way. Is that what you actually mean? If so, consider... `Object.prototype.toString.call(Array.prototype) === '[object Array]'; // true`

Comment: @am not i am: That's what I initially meant, thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the prototype of the `Array` class is the/an `Array` instance, that has a custom display on Webkit consoles. So it's the prototype you want actually.

And its empty, because you are storing values always on the instance (`myArray`) never on/in its prototype.

To expand methods and fields do this:

```
for-in or Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(myArray));
```

Comment: Did you mean Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(myArray));?